# Array.forEach with objects returns references

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

As demonstrated below, it appears that `Array.forEach(myObject => callback)` returns `myObject` as a reference to the exact object in my `Array`.  Is there any built-in or graceful way to return an unreferenced copy of `myObject` in an `Array.forEach` without calling something like `myObject = _.cloneDeep(myObject)` on each iteration?

Thanks.

```js
const trades = [
  { qty: 0 },
  { qty: 2 }
];

trades.forEach((trade, index) => {
  trade.qty += 1;
  trades[index].qty += 1;
  console.log(trade);
});

console.log(trades);
```

Comment: there is not; if you want copies of the elements in your array, you need to make them yourself.

Comment: There is no real way to do this in Javascript.  If you are already using lodash, then go with one of their clone functions, JQuery has $.extend which works as well.

Comment: Why not use `.map()`, and build a _new_ object every time you loop, keeping the original unchanged: `const new_trades = trades.map(({qty}) => ({qty: qty+2}));`

Comment: I'll stick with lodash's cloneDeep... thanks all